# Setting the Color on the row of the JTable using JColorChooser

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am novice to Swing. I just started Swing couple of weeks ago and I stuck at some point..

I have designed a `JTable` having some rows on clicking (right) it opens a popup menu which have "CHANGE ROW COLOR" option (`JMenuItem`),on clicking which `JColorChooser` opens up and user can choose the color and same color will be set to the selected row.

Is it possible to do it? How?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA8u2.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYHf2.jpg)

Comment: To enable copy&paste, please post your code as formatted text, not as image.

Comment: There is a very similar demo in the Java Tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ability to color each row separately then one way is to store the Color as part of the data in the TableModel. So you will need to add the Color as a column in the model.

But you will not want to display this column in the view of the table so you will need to remove it from the view:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn(...) );
```

Next you will need to add custom rendering for the table. One way to do this is to add rendering for the entire row. Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an example of this approach.

So the basic code for the rendering would be something like:

```
Color background = table.getTableModel.getValueAt(row, ???);

if (background != null)
    c.setBackground( background );
```

And when you display the color choose you would need to save the Color to the TableModel:

```
table.getTableModel().setValueAt(color, table.getSelectedRow(), ???);
```

Comment: I am using default table model and populating the table at runtime so it still coloing the entire table it would be best if you share some code how to add color as a colom and apply your concept as it is giving error in my case

Comment: @anrdggle, `it would be best if you share some code ` - I have given you working code to start with. Read the link and download the demo code. How is adding a column with Color objects any different than adding a column with String objects? If you want help then post an [mcve] that demonstrates what you have tried. I can't possible guess what the error is that you have, since I am not a mind reader.

Comment: Thanks Mann it took me time to understand what you said was working for me......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to save the row & the color in a `map<Integer, Color>`

```
(use table.getSelectedRow() )
```

To capture the color from the JColorchooser, use :
 `Color selectedColor = myColorChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedColor();`

Then, modify the default renderer :

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
                        column);

                if (listOfColor.containKey(row)) {

                    c.setBackground(listOfColor.get(row));

                }

                DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) c;
                centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                return c;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ....but problem is How to capture the color from Jcolor chooser and then set it on the table ....In the above mentioned link no jcolorchooser is used...

Comment: I edited my answer to give you the way to get the color from the JColorChooser.

Comment: I tried to use the method but still its painting the whole table and not the selected row

Comment: Ctrl C + Ctrl V, and uses " { } " from stackoverflow.